# Generic type that addresses 'path' in the object

Tags: typescript

Consider the code

```
/* eslint-disable */
type Primitive = boolean | null | number | string;

export type DataAddress<T> = T extends Primitive ? [T] : ObjectAddress<T>;

export type ObjectAddress<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, ...DataAddress<T[K]>];
}[keyof T];

type X = { x: boolean[] }

function f(...args: DataAddress<X>) {

}


f('x1') 
/* TS2345: Argument of type ["x1"] is not assignable to parameter of type
 ["x", ...any[]] | ["x", number, false] | ["x", number, true]
 */
```

The question is where does `["x", ...any[]]` come from and how to fix the code so that the type here will be `["x", number, false] | ["x", number, true]` only?

Comment: Arrays map to arrays in mapped types, but when you index with `keyof T` at the end, this becomes the full key set (including `"length"` and `"push"`). When writing a distributive type over arrays you want to restrict the keys to just numeric indices.  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq0RQN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz the end goal is to have a generic type that results to the union of all possible combinations of 'paths' in the given type. Like if you have `T = [number, 'foo' | 'bar']`, `DataAddress<T>` expected to be `[0, number] | [1, 'foo] | [1, 'bar']`

Comment: If I try the values from my previous comment with your playground's code it throws `TS2322: Type number is not assignable to type "0" | "1"`, but it can be fixed with `type ParseInt<T> = T extends \`${infer N extends number}\` ? N : T` I suppose... I am testing different scenarios and this is the only issue so far

Comment: Look at the last line in the code from your last link, it shows `type Show = ["0", number] | ["1", "foo"] | ["1", "bar"]`, not `type Show = [0, number] | [1, "foo"] | [1, "bar"]`. I am talking about the difference between `"0"` and `0`. I expect array indicies to be numbers in the 'path', not strings. But as I said, this can be fixed with `type ParseInt<T> = T extends \`${infer N extends number}\` ? N : T`. What do you think about this code? https://tsplay.dev/mpzRpw

Comment: Oh wow, okay, thanks, I was blind to it. TypeScript uses `"0"` and not `0` for the first key of a tuple type, and so on.  That's just the way it writes the keys. Feel free to parse them into numbers if you want, although this really seems out of scope for the question as asked.  Since you're not asking about these in the question could I just answer with my suggestion as-is? Or do you want to [edit] to make the question more complex by specifying exactly how `keyof T` should work for tuples.

Comment: Sure, go on and post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having with

```
type ObjectAddress<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, ...DataAddress<T[K]>];
}[keyof T];
```

is caused by the `[keyof T]` at the end there.  Your `ObjectAddress<T>` is what's known as a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) which is what you get when you write a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it will all its keys, producing a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the property value types.

Or at least, that's what it's supposed to do, and for "regular" object types it works as advertised.  But when `T` is an [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) or a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) things go wrong.  The mapped type `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯}` only iterates over the numeric-like keys and [produces another array or tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  *But*, the `keyof T` at the end is *not* just the numeric-like keys.  It's all the keys of the array type `T`, including `"length"`, `"push"`, et cetera.  And so you don't end up with just the union of `[K, ...DataAddress<T[K]>]` for each numeric `K`, you also get the union of all the other members, like `number` for `length`, and some function type for `push`, et cetra.  It's a mess.

One workaround is therefore to check if `T` is arraylike, and if so, only index with `number` as opposed to `keyof T`.  Maybe like this:

```
type ObjectAddress<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, ...DataAddress<T[K]>];
}[(T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown) & keyof T];
```

Here the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) evaluates to `number` for arraylike things, and `unknown` for nonarrays.  When we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) that with `keyof T` it evaluates to `number & keyof T` (which is likely to be `number`) when `T` is arraylike, or just `keyof T` when `T` is a nonarray.

Once we make that change your example behaves as intended:

```
type X = { x: boolean[] }
type Z = DataAddress<X>
//   ^? type Z = ["x", number, false] | ["x", number, true]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFARge3wBsIBDAOygB8pyBXIo62upXCOZgZ2EXIHMA3AChhEAB5h8cYFFCQoAEVLBSAQQAmGuBC5cAPABUAfFByGoE4BHIausRCjSYoAfigBtQwF0oALigAeVwAKwgAY2BNbV0DExExSWlZeWhgsMjonT0jUxwAb2EoTwBpKARKAGsIEHwAMygfAI8SgBooADou5VUs2KMW72NvEQBfDwAKCysbOygdUg18ciIQKAoQD193ejYOfyg6ckryfAB3cgBKKAAyKGrahp8E1KgADTMofKhxAIJiMjkLZQUbCV4ALU+PXUWmyBjexmEAHokcUoAA9dwQz4eABE4lx7V27Dg7TqpCIXAgvhoeIJRNYJPavDo1OEQA)